# Execute code only on rows with a certain value for a given column

Tags: python, pandas

```
df_counted = df_original[['CATEGORICAL_COLUMN']].value_counts(ascending=False).reset_index(name='countt')
df_filtered_table = df_counted[df_counted.countt > 3]
```

I have this code already running that works. What it does is basically for the given `CATEGORICAL_COLUMN`, it will keep rows if count of each distinct value of `CATEGORICAL_COLUMN` is more than 3.

However, I would like to do this only for rows that are `df_original[['BINARY_COLUMN']] == 1`.

How can do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove double `[]` in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df_counted = (df_original.loc[df_original['BINARY_COLUMN'] == 1, 'CATEGORICAL_COLUMN']
                         .value_counts(ascending=False)
                         .reset_index(name='countt'))
```